# incorrect alignment when usind subequations and alignat in combination

Tags: alignat

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[utf8,ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}  
\usepackage[fleqn,centertags]{mathtools}
\begin{document}

This is ordinary text and below 3 blocks of equations. The first one without using subequations.
\begin{alignat}{2}
 &a     &&=b ~,\label{1a}\\[1ex]
 &alpha &&=beta~,\label{1b} \\[1ex]
 &c     &&=\frac{\num{72000}\cdot\num{50000}\,(1 - \num{0.30})}{\num{50000}\,(1 - \num{0.30}) -
           2\cdot\num{72000}\cdot\num{0.25}^2} = \SI{96923}{kN/m^2} \label{1c} \\[1ex]
 &cc    &&=\frac{\num{72000}\cdot\num{50000}\,(1 - \num{0.30})}{\num{50000}\,(1 - \num{0.30}) -
           2\cdot\num{72000}\cdot\num{0.25}^2} = \SI{96923.08}{kN/m^2} \label{1d}
\end{alignat}%
The second block uses the subequation environment.
{\allowdisplaybreaks [4]
\begin{subequations}\label{1}
%\noeqref{1a,1b,1c,1d}
\begin{alignat}{2}
 &a     &&=b ~,\label{1a}\\[1ex]
 &alpha &&=beta~,\label{1b} \\[1ex]
 &c     &&=\frac{\num{72000}\cdot\num{50000}\,(1 - \num{0.30})}{\num{50000}\,(1 - \num{0.30}) -
           2\cdot\num{72000}\cdot\num{0.25}^2} = \SI{96923}{kN/m^2} \label{1c} \\[1ex]
 &cc    &&=\frac{\num{72000}\cdot\num{50000}\,(1 - \num{0.30})}{\num{50000}\,(1 - \num{0.30}) -
           2\cdot\num{72000}\cdot\num{0.25}^2} = \SI{96923.08}{kN/m^2} \label{1d}
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}}%
The alignment on the left side is fine in both cases. However, in the second case there is too much horizontal space left of the "=" sign. When the equation (5d) is removed, or if I reduce the length of (5d) by deleting one or more digits again, the alignment is fine, as can be seen below.
{\allowdisplaybreaks [4]
\begin{subequations}\label{1}
%\noeqref{1a,1b,1c,1d}
\begin{alignat}{2}
 &a     &&=b ~,\label{1a}\\[1ex]
 &alpha &&=beta~,\label{1b} \\[1ex]
 &c     &&=\frac{\num{72000}\cdot\num{50000}\,(1 - \num{0.30})}{\num{50000}\,(1 - \num{0.30}) -
           2\cdot\num{72000}\cdot\num{0.25}^2} = \SI{96923}{kN/m^2} \label{1c} \\[1ex]
 &cc    &&=\frac{\num{72000}\cdot\num{50000}\,(1 - \num{0.30})}{\num{50000}\,(1 - \num{0.30}) -
           2\cdot\num{72000}\cdot\num{0.25}^2} = \SI{96923}{kN/m^2} \label{1d}
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: I'd say the first alignment is wrong too many &.

Answer (score 1):

You're being unlucky. As you can see, the tags in the second display are misaligned: probably `amsmath` should do better in this case and, at least, issue a warning that the alignment is too wide.

Since you're using `fleqn`, you can solve the issue by pretending that the long equation is actually a bit shorter.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}  
\usepackage[fleqn,centertags]{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

This is ordinary text and below 3 blocks of equations. The first one without using subequations.
\begin{alignat}{2}
 &a     &&=b ~,\label{1a}\\[1ex]
 &alpha &&=beta~,\label{1b} \\[1ex]
 &c     &&=\frac{\num{72000}\cdot\num{50000}\,(1 - \num{0.30})}{\num{50000}\,(1 - \num{0.30}) -
           2\cdot\num{72000}\cdot\num{0.25}^2} = \SI{96923}{kN/m^2} \label{1c} \\[1ex]
 &cc    &&=\frac{\num{72000}\cdot\num{50000}\,(1 - \num{0.30})}{\num{50000}\,(1 - \num{0.30}) -
           2\cdot\num{72000}\cdot\num{0.25}^2} = \SI{96923.08}{kN/m^2} \label{1d}
\end{alignat}
The second block uses the subequation environment.
\begin{subequations}\label{1}
\begin{alignat}{2}
 &a     &&=b ~,\label{x1a}\\[1ex]
 &alpha &&=beta~,\label{x1b} \\[1ex]
 &c     &&=\frac{\num{72000}\cdot\num{50000}\,(1 - \num{0.30})}{\num{50000}\,(1 - \num{0.30}) -
           2\cdot\num{72000}\cdot\num{0.25}^2} = \SI{96923}{kN/m^2} \label{x1c} \\[1ex]
 &cc    &&=\frac{\num{72000}\cdot\num{50000}\,(1 - \num{0.30})}{\num{50000}\,(1 - \num{0.30}) -
           2\cdot\num{72000}\cdot\num{0.25}^2} = \SI{96923.08}{kN/m^2}
           \hspace{-2em}
           \label{x1d}
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

1. Never use `\allowdisplaybreaks` in the final version of a document. You may use it in the preamble when writing the document, but at the end the page breaks in displays have to be carefully chosen.
2. It makes no sense to load `ansinew`. Remove the `inputenc` call.
3. Why left alignment of the left-hand sides?

[image]